# Animate a div element from bottom to top in WordPress with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-animate

I want to create a menu system based on [this:](http://boston.html.themeforest.createit.pl/onepager/index.html)

The idea is to have the menu fixed at the bottom that floats to the top of the browser window when any of the menu items are pressed (from index) and vica versa when you go back to the index page. I want the menu to be fixed at the top on all the sub-pages except from index.

I've created an example [here](http://www.designkompaniet.no/sandbox/) that might make it easier to understand what I mean. In this example I'm using this jQuery code:

```
    $('#nav-wrap').click(function(event) {

    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#nav-wrap').animate({
        bottom: ( $(window).height() - $("#nav-wrap").height() )
    }, 2000, function(){

    document.location = $(this).attr('href');

    });
    return false;
})
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="nav-wrap">

        <nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'footer-menu')); ?>
        </nav>

</div><!--#nav-wrap -->
```

This basically does what I want, except for the return url from the menu does not work. I just get undefined url in return as you can see in the example above. Does anyone know how to solve this or maybe a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that within your event handler, `this` refers to div#nav-wrap, which doesn't have a href attribute.

Attach the handler to the anchor tags instead:

```
$('#nav-wrap a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href= $(this).attr('href');

  $('#nav-wrap').animate({
    bottom: ( $(window).height() - $("#nav-wrap").height() )
  }, 2000, function(){
    document.location = href;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

This does unfortunately not solve my problem as I still get undefined url in return :(